# How to connect to RESTFul webservice using SSL certificate in java

Tags: java, rest

I want to connect to a RESTFul web service which uses SSL certificate authentication.
When i use the same url in my browser, it works.
But when i write a code in java it does not, not sure what am i missing?
looks like i am not passing certificate, are there any inbuilt apis which can do that for me?
Below is my code,

```
URL url = new URL("SomeURL");
HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
con.setRequestMethod("GET");
con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json")

con.getResponseCode();// Timesout
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [HttpsURLConnection: Connection Timed out error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16895762/httpsurlconnection-connection-timed-out-error)