# Paypal HttpHostConnectException

Tags: java, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm having a little trouble setting up Paypal and seem to be getting a `HttpHostConnectException` all the time (See full stacktrace below) I though that this could be an issue with the firewall but the networks team have guaranteed that they are allowing the address through the firewall. So does anyone have any suggestions on what might be causing this?

```
org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com:443 [api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/173.0.82.83] failed: Connection timed out: connect
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.HttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(HttpClientConnectionOperator.java:140)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:318)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:363)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:219)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:195)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:86)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:108)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:106)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:57)
at uk.co.cdl.webclient.servicefacade.payment.PaypalPaymentService.paypalHttpCall(PaypalPaymentService.java:192)
at uk.co.cdl.webclient.servicefacade.payment.PaypalPaymentService.registerPaypalExpressCheckoutTransaction(PaypalPaymentService.java:125)
at uk.co.cdl.webclient.model.paypal.RegisterPaypalPayment.doPost(RegisterPaypalPayment.java:41)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:999)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:565)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:309)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:239)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.HttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(HttpClientConnectionOperator.java:123)
... 31 more
```

Here's my Java code for the request

```
public HashMap<String, String> paypalHttpCall(final String methodName, List<NameValuePair> nvps) {
    String responseText = "";
    HashMap<String, String> responseNvp = null;

    CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientHelper.getDefaultHttpClient(30000);
    Status status = Status.HEALTHY;
    String description = "Paypal Connection Successful";

    addPostParameterIfNotEmpty(nvps, Paypal.METHOD, methodName);
    addPostParameterIfNotEmpty(nvps, "VERSION", this.paypalEndpointVersion);
    addPostParameterIfNotEmpty(nvps, "PWD", this.paypalPassword);
    addPostParameterIfNotEmpty(nvps, "USER", this.paypalUsername);
    addPostParameterIfNotEmpty(nvps, "SIGNATURE", this.paypalSignature);
    CloseableHttpResponse postResponse = null;      
    try {
        super.transactionStart();

        /* getExternalURL() returns https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp
         *
         */
        if (!UrlHelper.isAValidFullURL(getExternalURL())) {
            // shouldn't happen, but we're toasted if it does, so don't even try
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("bad url: "+getExternalURL());
        }

        final HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(getExternalURL());
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps, "UTF-8"));
        postResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost); // Connection timeout here

    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        status = Status.DEAD;
        description = "We through an IOException so something bad has happened.";
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        super.transactionFinish(status, description);
    }

    return responseNvp;
}
```

Comment: Are you able to prove the networks team's claim? (Did they show it to you or did they tell you this?) e.g. Are you able to access and ping the address in question from the environment the program is executing from? I'm not saying the networks team is lying or doing a bad job, but sometimes careless mistakes happen and sometimes miscommunication can occur.

Comment: They are certain that it has been added. It seems odd as I can now hit it in my browser but not in my code but it is sending over the same request.

Comment: That is odd. By chance do you have the application deployed locally? If it's deployed remotely then the networks team might have opened the connection for your local machine but not for the machine the application is deployed on.

Comment: Its running locally on my machine

Comment: How do you test it in your browser ?

Comment: @ToYonos I've share some of my java code around where it makes the request hope it helps

Comment: So `https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp` works in your browser but in your code, running on your machine, it does not work ?

Comment: @ToYonos Correct and I can even do a `curl -v https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp` and get a response (Though it has said about issuer of local certificates). The only place I can't seem to hit it is when sending the request through code

Comment: is this code working : http://pastebin.com/3L935xzQ ? For me it gives `HTTP/1.1 200 OK`

Comment: @ToYonos no it didn't I got the exact same error

Comment: Same with another https url, like https://www.google.fr/ ?

Comment: @ToYonos nope doesn't work I get the exact same error but with `Connect to www.google.com:443 [www.google.com/173.194.66.99, www.google.com/173.194.66.103, www.google.com/173.194.66.104, www.google.com/173.194.66.105, www.google.com/173.194.66.106, www.google.com/173.194.66.147] failed: Connection timed out: connect` instead of saying paypal

Comment: In your machine, does `telnet www.google.com 443` work ?

Comment: @ToYonos The response I got from doing `telnet www.google.com 443` was `Connecting To www.google.com...Could not open connection to the host, on port 443: Connect failed` Could this still be a firewall issue?

Comment: Ok, I am positive now, it IS a firewall issue, port 443 is not opened. I think it's working in your browser because this one is using a proxy.

Comment: @ToYonos right thanks I will send the log back to our networks team

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the discussion with the OP in the comment section, I'm pretty sure it's a firewall issue. It's impossible to connect through `telnet` with the port 443, whatever the target, google or paypal.

This diagram, found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16897062/2003986) is pretty useful when you are stuck like this :

[image: Steps]

Comment: I am more then happy to reward you with the 250 points as you have been a huge help but I am just going to wait for the log I have sent back to our networks team to come back to see what they say, however +1 for now.

Comment: On that note: 

**Do not-under any circumstance-use Telnet to verify connectivity to PayPal API endpoints or other IP addresses.** As Telnet is not SSL-aware and does not acknowledge the SSL handshake, this may trigger a temporary blacklist on the PayPal side, further complicating troubleshooting.

Use CURL or OpenSSL instead.

Source: https://ppmts.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/733

Comment: @PayPal_Martin Does not *initiate* the SSL handshake. The client side of SSL does the initiating: the acknowledging, or rather the responding, is done by the server. The document is wrong.

Comment: Technically, that explanation should be mended - The message stays the same. If we have an incoming TCP connection and it is not followed up by an SSL handshake, the originating IP address will eventually be blocked.

Comment: Turns out that the firewall was still blocking me but then we found out that we were also being blocked by the proxy so thanks, enjoy the 250 points they were well spent.