# azure-webapp-maven-plugin happens error "Socket operation on nonsocket: configureBlocking" while deploying maven app to azure server

Tags: azure, sockets, deployment, timeout

when I execute mvn azure-webapp:deploy in cmd, a socket error happens.

```
情報: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request to {s}->https://dc.services.visualstudio.com:443: --Socket operation on nonsocket: configureBlocking
2 15, 2020 6:42:46 午後 com.microsoft.applicationinsights.core.dependencies.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
```

I run this goal at a cloud server, windows 2016. 
  It seems maven cannot connect with azure server to start to deploy.
  I have tried in my local machine with same command, it runs well. 
  Can anybody help me what the issue is in my cloud server, please?

execution logs:

```
mvn  azure-webapp:deploy
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] -------------------------< housecom.co.jp:hcm >-------------------------
[INFO] Building hcm 1.0
[INFO] --------------------------------[ war ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- azure-webapp-maven-plugin:1.9.0:deploy (default-cli) @ hcm ---
[WARNING] You are using an old way of authentication which will be deprecated in future versions, please change your configurations.
[INFO] Authenticate with ServerId: azure-auth
[INFO] [Correlation ID: d45c8e88-35ea-43cd-8e63-7cb343e9ffcb] Instance discovery was successful
[ERROR] [Correlation ID: d45c8e88-35ea-43cd-8e63-7cb343e9ffcb] Execution of class com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AcquireTokenCallable failed.
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0 (Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect (DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect (AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress (AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect (AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect (PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect (SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect (Socket.java:589)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect (SSLSocketImpl.java:666)
    at sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect (BaseSSLSocketImpl.java:173)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect (NetworkClient.java:180)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer (HttpClient.java:463)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer (HttpClient.java:558)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init> (HttpsClient.java:264)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New (HttpsClient.java:367)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient (AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:191)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0 (HttpURLConnection.java:1162)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect (HttpURLConnection.java:1056)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect (AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:177)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0 (HttpURLConnection.java:1340)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream (HttpURLConnection.java:1315)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream (HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:264)
    at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AdalOAuthRequest.configureHeaderAndExecuteOAuthCall (AdalOAuthRequest.java:145)
    at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AdalOAuthRequest.send (AdalOAuthRequest.java:83)
    at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AdalTokenRequest.executeOAuthRequestAndProcessResponse (AdalTokenRequest.java:87)
    at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationContext.acquireTokenCommon (AuthenticationContext.java:930)
    at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AcquireTokenCallable.execute (AcquireTokenCallable.java:70)
    at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AcquireTokenCallable.execute (AcquireTokenCallable.java:38)
    at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AdalCallable.call (AdalCallable.java:47)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:748)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
2 15, 2020 6:42:46 午後 com.microsoft.applicationinsights.core.dependencies.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
情報: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request to {s}->https://rt.services.visualstudio.com:443: [Socket operation on nonsocket: connect
INFO] ------------------------------2 15, 2020 6:42:46 午後 com.microsoft.applicationinsights.core.dependencies.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
情報: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request to {s}->https://dc.services.visualstudio.com:443: --Socket operation on nonsocket: configureBlocking
2 15, 2020 6:42:46 午後 com.microsoft.applicationinsights.core.dependencies.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
情報: Retrying request to {s}->https://rt.services.visualstudio.com:443
2 15, 2020 6:42:46 午後 com.microsoft.applicationinsights.core.dependencies.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
情報: Retrying request to {s}->https://dc.services.visualstudio.com:443
----------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  33.361 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-02-15T18:42:46+09:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.microsoft.azure:azure-webapp-maven-plugin:1.9.0:deploy (default-cli) on project hcm: java.io.IOException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

cloud env:

```
Apache Maven 3.6.0 (97c98ec64a1fdfee7767ce5ffb20918da4f719f3; 2018-10-25T03:41:47+09:00)
Maven home: C:\work\maven\bin\..
Java version: 1.8.0_221, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\jre
Default locale: ja_JP, platform encoding: MS932
OS name: "windows server 2016", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

the right process in my local machine:

```
mvn azure-webapp:deploy
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] -------------------------< housecom.co.jp:hcm >-------------------------
[INFO] Building hcm 1.0
[INFO] --------------------------------[ war ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- azure-webapp-maven-plugin:1.9.0:deploy (default-cli) @ hcm ---
[WARNING] You are using an old way of authentication which will be deprecated in future versions, please change your configurations.
[INFO] Authenticate with ServerId: azure-auth
[INFO] [Correlation ID: 88a3f90c-4396-49c9-8487-0ec3f040a578] Instance discovery was successful
[INFO] Updating App Service Plan...
[INFO] Updating target Web App...
[INFO] Successfully updated Web App.
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource to E:\testworkspace\hcm-dev\target\azure-webapp\HC-2-PsdOC0dd1-27f80ebb-ca1b-4cb9-b59c-bb970337311a
[INFO] Trying to deploy artifact to HC-WEBAPP-PO2C56...
[INFO] Deploying the war file hcm-1.0.war...
[INFO] Successfully deployed the artifact to https://hc-wx-pocasdf01.azurddewebsites.net2
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  01:25 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-02-15T17:27:16+09:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

solved, refer to the post [HttpsURLConnection: Connection Timed out error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16895762/httpsurlconnection-connection-timed-out-error).

I finally found my cloud computer is offline to internet, and browse with a proxy server!!